# Serialize exceptions and deserialize them as a base type

Tags: c#, exception, serialization

We have an application that consists of two different Processes. Process B does some processing while process A hosts the UI. A and B always run on the same machine and communicate via a custom IPC layer. Now I want to add exception handling to that IPC layer, for example:

```
Process A                Process B
---
Button_Click()   
                         DoStuff()
                         throw new ArgumentException()
catch(ArgumentException)
```

This means, A may call B, which then throws an exception that should be caught and handled in A.

To achieve this I need a mechanism to serialize and deserialize exceptions. I know that exceptions are `[Serializable]` so I could use `BinaryFormatter` or Json.net. The problem is however, that both processes have different assemblies loaded, meaning that some exception types that exists in A might not exist in B (or vice versa). This means I'd have to somehow encode the type I want to deserialize in addition to the actual exception type.

The desired behavior is then: whenever we encounter an exception, we serialize that exception. Additionally, we add a field `targetType` which is the first base type of that exception that can be found in mscorlib (and some other assemblies that are guaranteed to be present in both processes). The deserializing side then constructs the type based on `targetType` and throws that.

### Example

In process A:

```
void ButtonClick() 
{
    try
    {
        // call Foo in process B
        IPCLayer.CallFoo();
    } 
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        // catches BException (which is now InvalidOperationException)
    }
}
```

In process B:

```
// type only exists in B
class BException : InvalidOperationException { ... }

void Foo() => throw new BException();
```

---

I've played around with `BinaryFormatter` and Json.net but I'm not 100% sure how I can apply  this behavior recursively (because of `InnerException`) to either of those frameworks. I guess I could use `JsonConverter<Exception>` in Json.net's case and I will play around with that for a bit, but I don't know if the same is possible for `BinaryFormatter` (or something similar).

Another similar problem is that certain types have to be serialized as references (similar to [`ObjRef`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting.objref?view=netframework-4.8)). I guess I could use the same mechanism for this.

Do you have any tips/snippets/solutions on how I can serialize exceptions and deserialize them as a base type thereof (including inner exceptions)?

Comment: You're describing .NET Remoting. The scenario you describe is a) already available and b) a bad idea for security reasons. Which is why BinaryFormatter is *actively* being removed from .NET Core. Anyone can inject arbitrary code through these serialized types. Since the mid 2000s it's standard practice to return well defined and sanitized error messages instead of serializing arbitrary exceptions

Comment: Instead of trying to build your own protocol, consider using gRPC. In gRPC you define the messages *and* errors accepted and returned by services. It's cross platform with [built-in support in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-6.0). .NET tooling can generate client/server code from message definitions. You'll also be able to use all available gRPC tools to test and debug your services

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yeah and .NET Remoting has been removed in .net core. I know about the security issues with `BinaryFormatter`, I only used it as an example because it supports the `ISerializable` interface. But I don't think it would be a problem anyway since none of these processes have special permissions and you'd need to hijack IO pipes in order to inject code.

Comment: The [Inter-process communication with gRPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/interprocess?view=aspnetcore-6.0) shows how to use IPC to communicate between two processes, using different network transports.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos we've decided against gRPC because our own system has less overhead in our specific scenario (from a maintainability perspective). I know there are different systems out there that do similar things and we made prototypes using them.

Comment: And afaik, gRPC doesn't support arbitrary .net exceptions either, yod'd have to map them from/to messages as well

Comment: `has less overhead in our specific scenario (from a maintainability perspective)` and yet, here you are, not knowing how to maintain errors. Opting for the very feature that doomed BinaryFormatter - serializing arbitrary types.

Comment: `gRPC doesn't support arbitrary .net exceptions either, yod'd have to map them from/to messages as well` that's the point! What you try to do is simply a bad idea, recognized as such since ... actually forever. It was only between 2000-2005 that people thought it was smart to send arbitrary exceptions across the wire, instead of having a well-defined API. And an API *includes* the error messages

Comment: `from a maintainability perspective` what about versioning? If you allow arbitrary exceptions, the client will break down if the types change even in the slightest. Not just a property change, but a *field* change. You'd have to deploy servers and clients in lockstep.

Comment: We aren't sending anything over the wire and we're our only API consumer. Both processes are running on the same machine and we always ship binaries of both processes together, so there is no versioning problem. We don't have many of the usual security issues that you'd have if you go *over the wire*.

Comment: And we do have an existing mechanism of handling errors (which basically makes everything an `Exception`, type erasure so to speak), but that's not ideal because we want to preserve exception types.